# Excel pivot table: How to hide Base Item when showing values as "Difference from..."?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, presentation

I'd like to create a pivot table with values presented as a difference from a specified Base Item. However, I'd like to hide Base Item itself, as it adds redundant empty space to a table.

Picture showing what I'm looking for:
[image: Desired result]

Is it doable? I'm looking for a solution that **does not require** hiding worksheet rows or using VBA macro.

Also, **I'd like to refrain from adding aditional columns to source table**.

Note: filtering out Base Item results in #N/A error as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Unacceptable to simply filter out A, I presume?

Comment: @AaronContreras Unfortunately, it won't work (see edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the base item when using it in a "Show values as..." setting.

You can, however, create a calculated items that calculate the difference from A, display those items and hide all original items.

In your PivotTable, click any item in the Row labels.

From the PivotTable Tools ribbon, go to Options > Fields, Items, & Sets > Calculated Item

You'll need to give it a unique name, such as using underscores or remove spaces.

Then create the formula for the field. Select your Dimension field in the Fields list. Select the B Item in the Items list and click Insert Item to add it to your Formula. Enter the a minus then Insert the A Item. Click Save and the new calculated field is added to your PivotTable. Repeat for Item C. Now you can hide the original Items and display only the calculated difference for Items B and C from Item A.

[image: IMG]

Comment: Interesting solution! I'll accept your answer, as it is value-dynamic (reacts to changes in source data's values) and solves my problem with all constraints (no row hiding, no macros, no additional columns in source table). Perfect!

However, there are some issues with this solution that everybody should take into account when applying it: 1. It may require a significant amount of work when PT is first created, 2. new entries in Dimension (A, B, C, in my case) require adding new Calculated Items, 3. Calculated Items seem to be memory-demanding and sometimes fail with large datasets.