# Show values as "Difference From" with a filter value as the "Base Field"?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, calculated-field

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608367/excel-pivot-table-how-to-hide-base-item-when-showing-values-as-difference-from), although I'm open to a VBA solution if applicable.

Essentially, I have a pivot table where I am trying to do one of two things:

1. Create a field where values for "Week 2" are show as the `Difference From` "Week 1" in a pivot table that is already filtered for only "Week 2". This is -- as OP in the aforementioned question said -- to avoid having to show blank columns in the pivot table. Currently, I'm seeing my "Week Number" variable show up as an option in the `Base Field` option, but when I select it I get a column full of `#N/A` errors.
2. Alternatively, I could include both "Week 1" and "Week 2" *within* my pivot table, and then hide the values for "Week 1" (the `Base Field`) some how. So far, however, I've not come up with a good way to do this aside from hiding rows, which I'd like to avoid.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide the base item when using it in a "Show values as..." setting.

You can, however, create a calculated item that calculates the difference from Week 1, display that item and hide both Week 1 and Week 2 items.

In your PivotTable, click any item in the Week field.

From the PivotTable Tools ribbon, go to Options > Fields, Items, & Sets > Calculated Item

You'll need to give it a unique name, such as using an underscore or remove the space.

Then create the formula for the field. Select your Weeks field in the Fields list. Select the Week 1 Item in the Items list and click Insert Item to add it to your Formula. Enter the a minus then Insert the Week 1 Items. Click Save and the new calculated field is added to your PivotTable. Now you can hide the original Week 1 and Week 2 and display only the calculated difference between Week 2 and Week 1

[image: Img]